# Looking to find missing information by comparing 2 arrays using LODASH

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, lodash

I have 2 API requests that return 2 arrays(1 Array for each API request as result) for which have 1 common value i.e. timestamp.

I am looking to compare both the arrays and find which Array items is missing in either(get difference in 2 different arrays) using LODASH.

So for eg here are 2 sets of array

```
array1 =  [
    [
      1564482000000,
      30.5
    ],
    [
      1564482300000,
      null
    ],
    [
      1564482000020,
      30.5
    ]
]


array2 =  [
    [
      1564482000000,
      30.5
    ],
    [
      1564482300000,
      null
    ],
    [
      1564482000010,
      10.5
    ]
]
```

In above case Array 1 have following value that Array 2 doesn’t have

[
  1564482000020,
  30.5
]

Similarly , Array 2 have following value that Array 1 doesn’t have

[
  1564482000010,
  10.5
]

**Expected Result**
I am looking to get result of missing value in 2 different arrays so

```
diff_array2 =     [
      1564482000020,
      30.5
    ]

diff_array1=     [
      1564482000010,
      10.5
    ]
```

I tried `XORBY` in Lodash it gives combine value so there is no way to find out which item was missing in Array 1 or Array 2 as the resulting array for XOR is 1 array. Items may or may not exist in either

**Code sample** here https://repl.it/repls/LateCorruptTypes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [differenceBy](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.14#differenceBy) passing the index of the item to use for comparison as the iteratee:

```
const diff_array2 = _.differenceBy(array1, array2, 0);    

const diff_array1 = _.differenceBy(array2, array1, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved without lodash.

I assumed the index of the two mismatching arrays of the example was just a coincidence. So what the following code will do, is filter all arrays from our array where we can't find an array inside the other array so that both index 0 and index 1 of the two are equal. If the arrays can contain array of a length bigger than 2, you can just iterate over the elements instead.

```js
var array1 = [[1564482000000,30.5],[1564482300000,null],[1564482000020,30.5]],
    array2 = [[1564482000000,30.5],[1564482300000,null],[1564482000010,10.5]];

function diff_arr(arr1, arr2) {
  return arr1.filter(a => !arr2.find(v => v[0] == a[0] && v[1] == v[1]))
}

console.log(diff_arr(array1, array2))
console.log(diff_arr(array2, array1))
```

If you need only the values from withing the arrays as a result, you can always apply `.flat()` afterwards!

With the snippet below you can also compare arrays where their inner arrays have a variable length:

```js
var array1 = [[1564482000000,30.5],[1564482300000,null],[1564482000020,30.5]],
    array2 = [[1564482000000,30.5],[1564482300000,null],[1564482000010,10.5]];

function diff_arr(arr1, arr2) {
  return arr1.filter(a => !arr2.find(e => e.every((v,i) => v == a[i])))
}

console.log(diff_arr(array1, array2))
console.log(diff_arr(array2, array1))
```